# C# custom control cursor position

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a custom control slider so I can adjust the appearance myself.

However, I can't find a way to get the cursor position relative to the control.
It would propably be easy to code for each control after plopping the controls into my program. But I'd like to have the full functionality inside the custom control project and only having to worry about getting a value from the slider once it's inside my program.

So I need to get the cursor tracking done inside the custom control project.
I've tried using the event here:

```
private void CustomSlider_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But the only position I'm able to get is the 'global' screen location of the cursor, which will not help me unless I know the position of the control.

I hope my question is clear, thanks.

Comment: Did you look at `e.X` and `e.Y`?

Comment: Look into using [`SetCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll have to Pinvoke it but it should give you what you need.

Comment: Just tried e.X and e.Y and it looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the cursor position within the control's event-handler or corresponding virtual method, use the `MouseEventArgs.Location`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location(v=vs.110).aspx)) property:

```
class CustomControl : Control {
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        Point cursorPos = e.Location;
    }
}
```

To obtain the cursor position outside the control, use the `Control.MousePosition`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx)) static property and the `PointToClient()`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx)) method:

```
CustomControl ctrl = ...
Point cursorPos = ctrl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
```